# Issues with Django deployed on the server only

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

This is the error message

```
Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <module 'api.urls' from '/app/api/urls.py'> (None:None) 'api/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>]], 'path': ''}
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not subscriptable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 848, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in <URLResolver <module 'api.urls' from '/app/api/urls.py'> (None:None) 'api/'>
Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <module 'api.urls' from '/app/api/urls.py'> (None:None) 'api/'>], [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>]], 'path': ''}
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not subscriptable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 848, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in <URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>
Not Found: / (edited)
```

As I've said. The deployment in the docker container executes properly. Running the server locally on my machine work wonderfully and doesn't cause any issues. This only happens if I attempt to deploy it on my server. The details are that this is a Django Rest Framework API that only has the admin page aside from the API routes.

Comment: Have you got two different settings files for development and production?

Comment: I don't. They're pulled from the same repo, the only difference being the .env that holds the database connection but that shouldn't impact it too much

Comment: Sorry if some questions may sound redundant but could you include the urls in `api/urls.py`

Comment: Yeah there you go https://hatebin.com/iucdyoqkfz

Comment: I'm not sure about the second error in the stack trace but the first indicates it can't find a match for the root path url. For wtv reason it wants this. You could try including one in your top level  urls.py file. Something like `path('', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('admin:index')))` just to redirect `/` to `/admin`. See if that silences the error. You'll need `from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView`

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue since I have the route that handles the admin in the application directory itself https://hatebin.com/pewwksqswz . As I've said all the routes work fine locally, including the admin one

Comment: Yes I see you have routes for `/admin` and `/api` but the error in the stacktrace you provided is saying it crashed trying to lookup a route for `/` which you don't have. I'm merely suggesting making `/` route to the admin index page.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I'll update as soon as I get a chance to try it

Comment: Nope. Still the same error

Comment: @Danoram could it be an issue with serving the admin static files? We managed to get it running before we tried to server static files, it only broke after we attempted to configure the static files

Comment: With the information I have about your project that is probably the next best thing to look into.